# How to remove a comma from a .txt file using an Ant script

Tags: sql, oracle, ant

I have an Ant script and an SQL script. The Ant script makes the SQL script to run against the database and it generates a `.txt` file with multiple rows. The `.txt` file contains values like:

```
'value1',
'value2',
'value3',
 .
 .
'valueN',
```

I want to remove the comma in the last row. Is there any Ant command that I can use to make this happen?

I am new to both Ant and SQL

Comment: @AIBlue: Its an acronym for 'Another Neat Tool'. That's why I wrote it like that.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [Ant replaceregexp task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html), f.e. :

```
<replaceregexp
  match=",[^,]*$"
  replace=""
  file="${temp.dir}/file.txt"
 />
```

The regex pattern looks for the last ','
**-- EDIT --** after comment 
Just put the `<replaceregexp>` snippet after the `<sqlexecquiet>` which generates your outputfile, adapted the snippet to your needs :

```
 <target name="runquery" depends="initialize">

     <sqlexecquiet
       driver="${jd.driver}"
       url="${database.url}"
       userid="${database.user}"
       password="${database.password}"
       delimiter="go"
       coldelimiter=";"
       print="yes"
       showheaders="true"
       onerror="continue"
       output="${temp.dir}/file.txt"
      >

      <replaceregexp
        match=",[^,]*$"
        replace=""
        file="${temp.dir}/file.txt"
      />

 </target>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But when I add the script that you suggested to my ANT script it displays an error. Here is the script that makes the sql query to generate the .txt file.
Can you please suggest where to add the script that you have mentioned

    <target name="runquery" depends="initialize">
    <sqlexecquiet driver="${jd.driver}"
      url="${database.url}"
      userid="${database.user}"
      password="${database.password}"
      delimiter="go"
      coldelimiter=";"
      print="yes"
      showheaders="true"
      onerror="continue"
      output="${temp.dir}/file.txt ">

Comment: It returns the following error: **The <replaceregexp> type doesn't support the nested " file" element**

Comment: @san did work for me with Ant 1.9.6. But normally it's right, only resources (fileset ..) allowed as nested element, also using byline="true" was wrong. Edited the snippet again - now it should work for you. BTW what's your Ant Version ?

Comment: Its Ant-1.6.4. But your edited script(the new one) is working perfectly now. Thanks mate. But can I ask you how this expression works? I have hard time understanding it.

Comment: @san ,([^,]*)$ or also working ,[^,]*$ means a ',' followed by anything but another ',' until the end of line, means the last ',' in your file

Answer (score 0):

You can add following **`<replaceregexp>`** task at the end of your build xml to remove it

```
<replaceregexp file="${temp.dir}/yourfile.txt"
               match=",([^,]*)$"
               replace=""
 />
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It's wrong to use byline="true" with that regex, cause it will remove all ',' from the file. Also you're just repeating my answer.